# Creating an index variable in R based on row index

Tags: r, indexing, row, data.table

I think it's time to ask for help. Suppose I have this data.frame or data.table

```
State   Date   Event 
CA      Oct27    1      
CA      Oct28    0      
CA      Oct29    0      
CA      Oct30    0      
CA      Oct31    1      
TX      Oct27    0      
TX      Oct28    1      
TX      Oct29    1      
TX      Oct30    0      
TX      Oct31    0      
TX      Nov1     0
```

I want to create a new binary variable, "active", that indicates whether there is an active event on a particular date and state (assuming that all events lasted three days). The value "1" in column "Event" indicates when the event started.  So, my data my would look like this:

```
State   Date   Event Active
CA      Oct27    1      1
CA      Oct28    0      1
CA      Oct29    0      1
CA      Oct30    0      0
CA      Oct31    1      1
TX      Oct27    0      0
TX      Oct28    1      1
TX      Oct29    1      1
TX      Oct30    0      1
TX      Oct31    0      1
TX      Nov1     0      0
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What language/format is the data in?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the table is ordered by `State` and then `Date`?

Comment: Is it possible that you have an event start on a day, the next day not appear on the table, but the day after next appear?

Comment: The table is in R and can be ordered. And yes, in reality the table does not have all the dates but I could add the missing dates if that facilitates the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the `data.table` solution. Here's what I think is a cleaner base R solution.

```
s <- split(df, df$State)

newlist <- lapply(s, function(x) {
  days <- c(which(x$Event==1)+1, which(x$Event==1)+2)
  x$Event[seq_along(x$Event) %in% days] <- 1
  x
  }
)

do.call(rbind, newlist)
```

First, split the data frame by State. For each state, identify the two days after an event starts. If those days are in the list, assign `1` to them. Lastly, put the states together.

It outputs:

```
      State  Date Event
CA.1     CA Oct27     1
CA.2     CA Oct28     1
CA.3     CA Oct29     1
CA.4     CA Oct30     0
CA.5     CA Oct31     1
TX.6     TX Oct27     0
TX.7     TX Oct28     1
TX.8     TX Oct29     1
TX.9     TX Oct30     1
TX.10    TX Oct31     1
TX.11    TX  Nov1     0
```

Comment: The best way to say thanks is with the check mark. You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Considering your table is sorted and you do not care about non adjacent days, you can try:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Active:=Event|c(0, head(Event,-1))|c(0,0,head(Event,-2)), State][
          , Active:=Active+0]

#    State  Date Event Active
# 1:    CA Oct27     1      1
# 2:    CA Oct28     0      1
# 3:    CA Oct29     0      1
# 4:    CA Oct30     0      0
# 5:    CA Oct31     1      1
# 6:    TX Oct27     0      0
# 7:    TX Oct28     1      1
# 8:    TX Oct29     1      1
# 9:    TX Oct30     0      1
#10:    TX Oct31     0      1
#11:    TX  Nov1     0      0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked and I;m still trying to digest your solution. Would it be possible to modify it to account for missing dates in the actual table?

Comment: Could this `head` stuff be done with the new `shift` operator, I wonder...?

Comment: I am using data.table 1.9.4 Franck ;)

Comment: @davidll what do you mean by missing dates? Nov1 for the state CA?

Answer (score 2):

Dude, this was a seriously challenging problem. I think I got it using `by()` to group by `State` and `Reduce()` to repeatedly apply vectorized logical OR `|` to the `Active` vector to account for any past day within the specified range (3) that had an event start.

```
df <- data.frame(State=c('CA','CA','CA','CA','CA','TX','TX','TX','TX','TX','TX'), Date=c('Oct27','Oct28','Oct29','Oct30','Oct31','Oct27','Oct28','Oct29','Oct30','Oct31','Nov1'), Event=c(1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0) );
E <- 3;
do.call(rbind,by(df,df$State,function(x) { s <- x$Event==1; x$Active <- Reduce(function(a,b) a|c(rep(F,b),s[-seq(length(s)-b+1,len=b)]),c(list(s),1:(E-1))); x; }));
##       State  Date Event Active
## CA.1     CA Oct27     1   TRUE
## CA.2     CA Oct28     0   TRUE
## CA.3     CA Oct29     0   TRUE
## CA.4     CA Oct30     0  FALSE
## CA.5     CA Oct31     1   TRUE
## TX.6     TX Oct27     0  FALSE
## TX.7     TX Oct28     1   TRUE
## TX.8     TX Oct29     1   TRUE
## TX.9     TX Oct30     0   TRUE
## TX.10    TX Oct31     0   TRUE
## TX.11    TX  Nov1     0  FALSE
```

An advantage of this solution is that it parameterizes the event duration, which means you can change it easily in the future:

```
E <- 2;
do.call(rbind,by(df,df$State,function(x) { s <- x$Event==1; x$Active <- Reduce(function(a,b) a|c(rep(F,b),s[-seq(length(s)-b+1,len=b)]),c(list(s),1:(E-1))); x; }));
##       State  Date Event Active
## CA.1     CA Oct27     1   TRUE
## CA.2     CA Oct28     0   TRUE
## CA.3     CA Oct29     0  FALSE
## CA.4     CA Oct30     0  FALSE
## CA.5     CA Oct31     1   TRUE
## TX.6     TX Oct27     0  FALSE
## TX.7     TX Oct28     1   TRUE
## TX.8     TX Oct29     1   TRUE
## TX.9     TX Oct30     0   TRUE
## TX.10    TX Oct31     0  FALSE
## TX.11    TX  Nov1     0  FALSE
```

The correctness of this solution depends on two assumptions, independently for each unique `State`: (1) there are no gaps in the `Date` sequence, and (2) the data.frame is ordered by `Date`.

---

Here's a different solution using `by()` again, but now with `seq()` to generate all dates covered by an event, and `merge()` to merge those dates back into the data.frame subset for a particular `State` to set `Active` to true. This solution relaxes both of the assumptions I mentioned above; the input data.frame now no longer has to be gapless or ordered. However, you now must coerce the `Date` column to class `Date` (as done in my demo below), although I would argue that's something that should always be done when you're working with dates.

```
df2 <- transform(df,Date=as.Date(Date,'%b%d'));
E <- 3;
transform(do.call(rbind,by(df2,df2$State,function(x) merge(x,data.frame(Date=unique(do.call(c,lapply(x$Date[x$Event==1],seq,by=1,len=E))),Active=T),all.x=T))),Active=replace(Active,is.na(Active),F));
##            Date State Event Active
## CA.1 2015-10-27    CA     1   TRUE
## CA.2 2015-10-28    CA     0   TRUE
## CA.3 2015-10-29    CA     0   TRUE
## CA.4 2015-10-30    CA     0  FALSE
## CA.5 2015-10-31    CA     1   TRUE
## TX.1 2015-10-27    TX     0  FALSE
## TX.2 2015-10-28    TX     1   TRUE
## TX.3 2015-10-29    TX     1   TRUE
## TX.4 2015-10-30    TX     0   TRUE
## TX.5 2015-10-31    TX     0   TRUE
## TX.6 2015-11-01    TX     0  FALSE
E <- 2;
transform(do.call(rbind,by(df2,df2$State,function(x) merge(x,data.frame(Date=unique(do.call(c,lapply(x$Date[x$Event==1],seq,by=1,len=E))),Active=T),all.x=T))),Active=replace(Active,is.na(Active),F));
##            Date State Event Active
## CA.1 2015-10-27    CA     1   TRUE
## CA.2 2015-10-28    CA     0   TRUE
## CA.3 2015-10-29    CA     0  FALSE
## CA.4 2015-10-30    CA     0  FALSE
## CA.5 2015-10-31    CA     1   TRUE
## TX.1 2015-10-27    TX     0  FALSE
## TX.2 2015-10-28    TX     1   TRUE
## TX.3 2015-10-29    TX     1   TRUE
## TX.4 2015-10-30    TX     0   TRUE
## TX.5 2015-10-31    TX     0  FALSE
## TX.6 2015-11-01    TX     0  FALSE
```

Comment: It works, much appreciated! Let me go through that to see your logic there because it has many functions and arguments involved.